# Which emergency number is my best bet?

Tags: cellphones, emergencies

After looking through a list of emergency numbers for the different countries, I've noticed that there are four main numbers: 112, 911, 999 and 000.

So, if I found myself in a country where I didn't know the emergency number, which number should I guess at first from the list of four above? How should my guess be different in each of the continents?

What should I do if none of them work?

Comment: This question is substantially similar to the proposed duplicate, but subtly different.  I would also note that the answer would depend on whether the call is made from a cell phone or a land line, and possibly on whether IP telephony is involved.

Comment: The information needed to answer this question is contained in the answers to the other one.

Comment: The answers to the other question are either incorrect or of rather low quality, but it is still more or less a duplicate. And it is also reasonable to argue for this question to be too broad.

Comment: I have heard, but have no evidence to support, that some countries offer 911 even though their own emergency number is officially different, because of the influence of American TV and movies.

Comment: The probability space is ill-defined. Does the number used in the largest number of countries win? Do you prefer large ones? Or touristic ones?